# How to drop a mysql database from a script using ~/.my.cnf?

Tags: bash

I need to drop a mysql database directlly from a script.

I create the file ~/.my.cnf and chmod 600.

`[client]
user = "**************"
password = "*********"
safe-updates`

My script includes this :

`CMD4="echo 'DROP DATABASE db_test;' | mysql"`

`curl -fs -- "$URL" | grep -q -- "$WORD1" && $CMD4`

I can´t execute the command I just get this output: 
'DROP DATABASE db_test;' | mysql

The database is not dropped.
What´s wrong with it?

Thanks

Comment: I've retagged assuming you're talking about bash. Feel free to correct it if I was wrong. I'm far from being a shell ninja but I suspect your pipe gets passed as argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enclose the below statement in Grave accent (``) instead of double quotes ("") where you are initializing the value of `CMD4` on the both

`echo 'DROP DATABASE db_test;' | mysql`

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't use *variable* to store code. Use *function* instead:

```
function dropdb {
    echo 'DROP DATABASE db_test;' | mysql # aren't you missing some arguments here?
                                          # like `-u username -p db`
}

curl -fs -- "$URL" | grep -q -- "$WORD1" && dropdb
```

Comment: You get slightly better portability without the `()` in your function definitions. They work in `sh` but they are more a bashism. I used them for ever until the same was pointed out.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for pointing out that in your turn! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the pipe using `mysql -Bse 'expression'`. So in your case, with the correct ~/.my.cnf setting you can simply do:

```
mysql -Bse "drop database db_test"
```

You also have the full range of mysql options as well. i.e. `mysql -h somehost -u someuser -p pass -Bse "expression"`

Comment: **-B, --batch** Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.